# Validate Confirm Password Angular

Tags: angular, forms, validation

My form have 1 formGroup which includes 2 formControls: Password and Confirm Password. I'm using password-matcher directive to check these 2 formControls are equal when user type in.

As you can see, the confirm password turn green when you typed in. But I want it turn green only password = confirm password. Or another word, it turns green when formGroup turns green.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o7zyas?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Currently your form's validity does not depend on the PasswordMatcherDirective, something is not wired properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have a solution for you [example code](https://angular-4jwshv.stackblitz.io)

EDIT: I didn't figure out that the site gave me the url to just the presentation, not the code too, so here is the [editor code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8xjee).

The things I've added were [ngClass] attribute on both input elements which will control the classes for validation states and I've created 2 classes in the css and removed angular ones (ng-valid, ng-touched, etc.)

Thanks to @ConnorsFan for pointing out that I didn't gave any explanation and it wasn't the link to the code, but rather to the concrete example.

Comment: You should include the relevant code, along with an explanation, in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I've just updated my answer with a better explanation on what I did, if you can, reconsider the downvote, thanks

Comment: Please note that I did not downvote your answer. It would still be better to put the relevant parts of the code directly in the answer, like you did in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48705400/1009922).