# Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send an email verification for the registering users but I am getting the following error:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1
>   Authentication Required. Learn more at\r\n 530 5.5.1 
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError v11sm5345109pgt.0 -
>   gsmtp\r\n

I have tried all the possible ways by enabling the "less secure" and other instructions but not understanding the error. please help me to sort out the problem.

My `.env` file is :

[image]

My Controller:

[image]

My mail.php:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myaccount@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'), ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('myaccount@gmail.com'),
'password' => env('*******'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => FALSE,
```

Comment: Do not add code as images. Please edit your question to include the code as part of the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `mail.php`, use this code instead of your

```
...
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host'   => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port'   => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from'   => [
   'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myaccount@gmail.com'),
   'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example')
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'myaccount@gmail.com'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', '*******'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => FALSE,
...
```

**EDIT:**
First parameter of the `env()` helper method is `name of environment variable` and second one is a fallback value if that variable isn't found. The reason why it didn't work is because Laravel wasn't able to find an `environment` variable under the name `myaccount@gmail.com` and `*******`.